# Add cloud-capabilities to existing application

Tags: mysql, cloud

We currently have an desktop application that is sold to small businesses and used as a server/client model application and we are in the early stages of researching the possibility of adding cloud-based syncing to the program.

Besides the obvious hurdles in transitioning/recoding the networking code of the program itself, there seem to be many additional questions related to the server/database selection, available cloud services, scalability, and more.

For example, currently the non-cloud application simply connects to a specified MySQL database file and then loads/views/updates data. This database can even be stored remotely on a server and accessed from multiple machines, for example:

```
db=New mySQLCommunityServer
db.host="12.23.56.57"
db.port=3306
db.databaseName="myData"
db.userName="userName"
db.Password="password1"

db.connect
```

But for a distributed cloud application, it would need to connect to a the same host and SQL database name but with each specific user's login and password and access their specific database and tables. Where would that translate into the code above?

A few questions arise:

1. Would a new entire database need to be created for each new user account that signs up?
2. If so, how would changes to table formatting be applied to all user databases. Assuming roughly 500-1000 users signup, having 500-1000 separate databases doesn't make much sense.
3. Would this be better accomplished using a service such as Amazon Web Services? Even there, it was a bit unclear how the "program user account" would translate onto their services.

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: Knowing the language the application is written in will be helpful.

Comment: This is just sample code to show connecting to a SQL database from any language, so the actual language doesn't matter. What I would need to figure out is where to enter/create credentials for the different users so they would have their own separate databases in "the cloud". Changing a user name or password doesn't do much when logging in to a database, but creating multiple Databases is clumsy and would be nearly impossible to maintain in the future.